# count children using rapturexml

Tags: iphone, xml-parsing

I am using to RaptureXML to parse an XML and I want to count how many children for a given tag. for example :

```
  <players>
      <coach>
          <name>Terry Collins</name>
          <year>1</year>
      </coach>

      <player number="7">
          <name>Jose Reyes</name>
          <position>SS</position>
      </player>

      <player number="16">
          <name>Angel Pagan</name>
          <position>CF</position>
      </player>

  </players>
```

For example under tag = players, I am going to have 3 children.
In RaptureXML, I don't see how we can do it.Are there any others parsing way to do it.Please advice.
Thanks

Comment: can you try calling `- (NSArray *)children:(NSString *)tagName` with `nil` for tagName?

Comment: Thanks Mike....i tried and it did work. I am still wondering why the tagName is nil... In an example above, should it be tagName = @"players"

Comment: the top level tag in this case is "players", so when you create an RXMLElement from the xml file (or whereever the xml is), the RXMLElement you get back will have a tag of "players". from there you want all the children - since you are looking for all children and not just ones with a certain tag, you pass in nil for tagName.

Comment: ok i got the idea now. So, the tagName should be nil all the times. Please correct me if i've made a mistake

Comment: if you want to get all the children regardless of their tagName then yep, just pass nil.

Answer (score 3):

You could use:

```
[rxml children:@"*"].count
```